# Overflow problems on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow

There is a problem that drive me crazy.
I'm modifying a website where all seems to be wide the 100% of the page at worst.
Modifying the browser window size the situation is the same.
Only on mobile devices the page is wider than the screen of some pixels. I can touch and move the page.
I have already tryed all the suggestions found here, on Stack Overflow:
I don't find overflowed divs, my html has the width 100%, there is not min-width divs in devices.
My website is test.fypper.com
What could be the problem?

Comment: Shrink the window down, right click, inspect element, and start hovering over elements in the DOM - as you hover over them, it will highlight them on the page. See which element is overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add class `.container` to div id `#home` but it behaves very strangely. I am not sure you are following bootstrap guidelines properly so you should probably look into it.

Anyway, if you want a quick fix, add `.container-fluid` to div `#home` and probably remove `padding: 10px;` from div `#content`.

I have not looked at other pages, you might have divs like `#another-page` and `#even-another-page`instead of `#home`. You can add `container-fluid` to each of them one-by-one but to save your time on typing, use more generic wrapper in your template. For example `main` tag with `.container-fluid` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there isn't if I substitute "padding: 20px 0" with padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"
Now padding left and right is 15px. The container is 100% wide.
My problem is solved, but I don't understand why the container needs 15px of padding left and right on some mobile browsers.